# On a relation between functions that both vanish on the same hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry

Say I have a differentiable manifold $M$ and a smooth function $f$ on $M$. Assume that the locus of points in $M$ satisfying $f = 0$ defines a submanifold $\Sigma$, and that there is another smooth function $h$ on $M$ which also vanishes on $\Sigma$. Further assume that the gradient of $f$ nowhere vanishes on $\Sigma$.

My question is the following. Is it always true that, on a vicinity around $\Sigma$, there is another (possibly not unique) smooth function $g$ such that, locally, one can write $h = g.f$?

Comment: Perhaps a better question is this: Is there a smooth function $g$ (on a neighborhood of $0\in\Bbb R$ so that $h=g\circ f$? Choose local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on $M$ so that $f=x^n$. Now what?

Comment: Good point! If you choose coordinates such that $f = x^n$, then the fact that $h=0$ everywhere on $\Sigma$ implies that $\partial_i h = 0$ for every $i=1, \dots, n-1$, and therefore $h$ can only be a function of the last coordinate $x^n$ -- which gives us $h = g(f)$ for some function $g$.

Comment: The reason why I was thinking about this was because I wanted to prove that the gradients of both $f$ and $g$ were proportional to each other on $\Sigma$, which would be true if $h = gf$ because $dh = g df + f dg$ and $f=0$ on $\Sigma$ by definition. But it also works if $h = g \circ f$ because now $dh = g'(0) df$.

Comment: This looks a bit weird though, because it seems to imply that the proportionality constant between the gradients is a constant, whereas $h = gf$ in principle allows the proportionality constant to depend on the position along $\Sigma$. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original claim is correct. The proof is a variant of a standard technique at the beginning of a differentiable manifolds course.

As I suggested, we choose local coordinates $x=(x^1,\dots,x^{n-1},x^n)$ so that $f(x)=x^n$. Let's write $x=(\bar x,t)$ with $\bar x = (x^1,\dots,x^{n-1})$ and $t=x^n$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, write
$$h(\bar x,t) - h(\bar x, 0) = \int_0^1 \frac d{du} h(\bar x,tu)\,du = t\int_0^1\frac{\partial h}{\partial x^n}(\bar x,tu)\,du.$$
Since $h(\bar x,0) = 0$ identically and $t=x^n=f(x)$, we set
$$g(\bar x,t) = \int_0^1\frac{\partial h}{\partial x^n}(\bar x,tu)\,du,$$
and we have $h=gf$, as desired.